records are duplicated while adding two different accounts once
I want to add two accounts. For that I will make use of the account dropdown. Every time I select an account number the site and container description is populated automatically. After that I will fill the require fields and click 'Update'.
When I click Update the entire page reloads. I should get 2 records only but I am getting four records which is not correct.
Although I did not face this issue while two similar accounts are added once.
Here's what the UI looks like:

inc_detail_transactions_write.jsp:
<c:otherwise>
  <sec:authorize access="hasAuthority(T(com.repsrv.tph2.cbs.authorization.CbsPointers).INVOICE_ENTRY)">
    <jsp:include page="inc_detail_transactions_write.jsp"/>
  </sec:authorize>
</c:otherwise>

inc_detail_transactions_write.jsp

<form id="detailForm" method="post" name="detailForm" onsubmit="return doUpdate();" action="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}">
  <input type="hidden" name="headerInvoiceStatus" value="${headerRec.invoiceStatus}" />
  <table id="writeTable" aria-describedby="writeTable" class="table table-center-alltable-sm table-no-top-border table-font-md detailInputTable table-sm table-borderless vertical-align" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing:0 6px;">
    <thead>
      <tr class="border_bottom">
        <th scope="col">
          <input type="checkbox" class=" selectAll" id="selectAll">
        </th>
        <c:if test="${multipleAccounts }">
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Account</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Site</th>
        </c:if>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Container Description</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Charge<br/>Type</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Service<br/>Date</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Service<br/>Code</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Charge Code</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Customer<br/>PO #</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Disposal<br/>Volume</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Disposal<br/>Unit of Measure</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Amt Inv<br/>from<br/>Hauler</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Amt to be<br/>Paid to<br/>Hauler</th>
        <c:if test="${multipleAccounts }">
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Bulk<br/>Mode</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Row<br/>Identifier</th>
        </c:if>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <c:set var="containerChains" value="" />
      <c:set var="containerNonBillChains" value="-1+-1" />
      <c:set var="containerFullChargeChains" value="-1+-1" />
      <c:set var="urContainerTypeChains" value="-1+-1" />
      <c:forEach var="container" items="${invoiceContainers }" varStatus="loop">
        <c:set var="containerChains" value="${container.container} ${containerChains}" />
        <c:set var="containerNonBillChains" value="${container.container}+Non_Bill ${containerNonBillChains}" />
        <c:set var="containerFullChargeChains" value="${container.container}+Full_Charge ${containerFullChargeChains}" />
        <c:set var="urContainerTypeChains" value="${container.container}+-1 ${urContainerTypeChains}" />
        <c:forEach items="${container.containerDetails }" var="containerDetail" varStatus="loop">
          <c:forEach var="chargeCode" items="${containerDetail.chargeCodes }">
            <c:set var="urContainerTypeChains" value="${container.container}+${containerDetail.urNumber} ${urContainerTypeChains}" />
          </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
      </c:forEach>
      <c:forEach var="transaction" items="${transactions }" varStatus="iterStatus">
        <c:set var="rowClass" value="" />
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${transaction.uiIdentifier eq 'EDI Transaction'}">
            <c:set var="rowClass" value="table-ediRow" /></c:when>
          <c:when test="${transaction.uiIdentifier eq 'AutoPay'}">
            <c:set var="rowClass" value="table-autoPayRow" /></c:when>
          <c:when test="${transaction.uiIdentifier eq 'eInvoice Transaction'}">
            <c:set var="rowClass" value="table-eInvoiceRow" /></c:when>
        </c:choose>
        <tr class="${rowClass }" id="row${iterStatus.count -1 }">
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].selected" data-varname="selected" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].update" value="${not empty transaction.container }" data-varname="update">
            <input type="hidden" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].ediTransaction" value="${transaction.uiIdentifier eq 'EDI Transaction'}" data-varname="ediTransaction">
            <input type="hidden" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].transactionId" value="${transaction.transactionId}" data-varname="transactionId">
          </td>
          <c:if test="${multipleAccounts }">
            <td>
              <select class="invAccount" data-rownum="${iterStatus.count -1 }" data-varname="bulkKey.account" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].bulkKey.account" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }bulkKey.account">
                <option value="-1">&nbsp;</option>
                <c:forEach items="${acctIds }" var="item">
                  <option ${transaction.account eq item ? 'selected' : '' } value="${item }">${item }</option>
                </c:forEach>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select class="invSite" data-rownum="${iterStatus.count -1 }" data-varname="bulkKey.site" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].bulkKey.site" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }bulkKey.site">
                <option value="-1">&nbsp;</option>
                <c:forEach var="site" items="${siteAccountMaps }">
                  <c:set var="accounts" value="${site.value}" />
                  <c:set var="acctChain" value="" />
                  <c:set var="acctSiteChain" value="" />
                  <c:forEach var="acct" items="${accounts}">
                    <c:set var="acctChain" value="${acct} ${acctChain}" />
                    <c:set var="acctSiteChain" value="${acct}+${site.key } ${acctSiteChain}" />
                  </c:forEach>
                  <option value="${site.key }" data-chained="${acctChain }" ${transaction.site eq site.key ? 'selected' : '' }>${site.key }</option>
                </c:forEach>
              </select>
            </td>
          </c:if>
          <td>
            <select class="invContainer" data-rownum="${iterStatus.count -1 }" data-varname="container" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].container" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }container">
              <option value="-1" data-chained="-1+-1 -1 ${acctSiteChain }">&nbsp;</option>
              <c:forEach var="container" items="${invoiceContainers }">
                <c:if test="${transaction.container eq container.container}">
                  <c:set var="selectedContainer" value="${container }" />
                </c:if>
                <c:set var="containerStatus" value="${container.containerCloseDate eq '0001-01-01' ? ' - Active' : ' - Inactive'}" />
                <option data-chained="${container.account }" ${transaction.container eq container.container ? 'selected' : '' } value="${container.container }" data-containertype="${container.containerType }" data-containersize="${container.containerSize }" data-compactor="${container.compactorflag }">${container.container }
                  <c:out value="${container.containerDescription } ${containerStatus }" />
                </option>
              </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" value="${transaction.serviceSource }" data-varname="serviceSource" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].serviceSource" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }serviceSource" />
            <input type="hidden" value="${selectedContainer.containerType }" data-varname="containerType" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].containerType" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }containerType" />
            <input type="hidden" value="${selectedContainer.containerSize }" data-varname="containerSize" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].containerSize" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }containerSize" />
            <input type="hidden" value="${selectedContainer.compactorflag }" data-varname="compactorFlag" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].compactorFlag" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }compactorFlag" />
            <input type="hidden" value="${iterStatus.count -1 }" data-varname="uiRowNumber" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1}].uiRowNumber" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1}uiRowNumber" />

          </td>
          <td>
            <select class="chargeType" autocapitalize="none" data-varname="chargeType" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].chargeType" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }chargeType">
              <option value="-1" data-chained="-1 ${containerChains }">&nbsp;</option>
              <option value="Non_Bill" ${transaction.noneUrNumberType eq 'Non Bill' ? 'selected' : '' } data-chained="-1 ${containerChains }">Non Bill</option>
              <option value="Full_Charge" ${transaction.noneUrNumberType eq 'Full Charge' ? 'selected' : '' } data-chained="-1 ${containerChains }">Full Charge</option>
              <c:set var="selectedEffDate" value="" />
              <c:set var="urFound" value="${transaction.noneUrNumberType eq 'Non Bill' or (transaction.noneUrNumberType eq 'Full Charge') }" />
              <c:forEach var="container" items="${invoiceContainers }">
                <c:forEach items="${container.containerDetails }" var="containerDetail" varStatus="loop">
                  <c:if test="${empty containerDetail.invoice or (containerDetail.invoice eq headerRec.invoiceNumber)}">
                    <option data-servicesource="${containerDetail.serviceSource}" data-customerpo="${containerDetail.scheduled }" data-servicedate="${containerDetail.serviceDate }" data-servicecode="${containerDetail.serviceCode }" ${containerDetail.urNumber eq transaction.noneUrNumberType
                      ? 'selected=selected' : '' } value="${containerDetail.urNumber }" data-chained="${container.container }">
                      <c:out value="${containerDetail.urNumber }" />
                    </option>
                    <c:set var="urFound" value="${urFound or (containerDetail.urNumber eq transaction.noneUrNumberType) }" />
                    <c:set var="urChains" value="${containerDetail.urNumber} ${urChains}" />
                  </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
              </c:forEach>
              <c:if test="${not urFound }">
                <option data-servicesource="${transaction.serviceSource}" data-customerpo="" data-servicedate="${transaction.serviceDate }" data-servicecode="${transaction.serviceCode }" selected=selected value="${transaction.noneUrNumberType }" data-chained="${transaction.container }">
                  <c:out value="${transaction.noneUrNumberType }" />
                </option>
              </c:if>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input class="datepicker" id="serviceDate" autocomplete="off" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].serviceDate" type="text" value="${transaction.serviceDate }" size=10 data-varname="serviceDate" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" value="${transaction.serviceCode }" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].serviceCode" size=12 data-varname="serviceCode" /> </td>
          <td>
            <select style="width: 100%;" class="chargeCode" data-varname="chargeCode" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].chargeCode" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1 }chargeCode">
              <option value="-1" data-chained="-1+-1 -1 -1+Full_Charge -1+Non_Bill ${urChains } ${ containerNonBillChains} ${urContainerTypeChains} ${containerFullChargeChains}">&nbsp;</option>
              <c:set var="selectedEffDate" value="" />
              <c:forEach var="fcCode" items="${fullchargeCodes }">
                <option data-effectivedate="${fcCode.effectiveDate}" value="${fcCode.code }" ${transaction.chargeCode eq fcCode.code ? 'selected' : '' } data-chained="${fcCode.container }+Full_Charge -1+-1">
                  <c:out value="${fcCode.description }" />
                </option>
                <c:if test="${transaction.chargeCode eq fcCode.code }">
                  <c:set var="selectedEffDate" value="${fcCode.effectiveDate }" />
                </c:if>
              </c:forEach>

              <c:set value="" var="nbType" />
              <c:forEach var="nonBillCode" items="${nonBillCodes }" varStatus="nbStatus">
                <c:if test="${nbType ne nonBillCode.type and (not empty nbType)}">
                  </optgroup>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${nbType ne nonBillCode.type}">
                  <optgroup label="${nonBillCode.type }" data-chained="${ containerNonBillChains}">
                </c:if>
                <c:set value="${nonBillCode.type }" var="nbType" />
                <option value="${nonBillCode.code }" ${transaction.chargeCode eq nonBillCode.code ? 'selected' : '' } data-chained="${ containerNonBillChains}">
                  <c:out value="${nonBillCode.description }" /> </option>
                <c:if test="${nbStatus.last }">
                  </optgroup>
                </c:if>
              </c:forEach>
              <c:forEach var="container" items="${invoiceContainers }">
                <c:forEach items="${container.containerDetails }" var="containerDetail" varStatus="loop">
                  <c:forEach var="chargeCode" items="${containerDetail.chargeCodes }">
                    <option ${transaction.chargeCode eq chargeCode.code ? 'selected' : '' } value="${chargeCode.code }" data-chained="${container.container}+${containerDetail.urNumber}">
                      <c:out value="${chargeCode.description }" />
                    </option>
                  </c:forEach>
                </c:forEach>
              </c:forEach>
              <c:if test="${not urFound }">
                <option selected value="${transaction.chargeCode }" data-chained="${transaction.container}+${transaction.noneUrNumberType}">
                  <c:out value="${transaction.chargeCodeDescription }" />
                </option>
              </c:if>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" value="${selectedEffDate }" data-varname="effectiveDate" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1}].effectiveDate" id="invoiceEntry${iterStatus.count -1}effectiveDate" />
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].customerPoNumber" size=12 data-varname="customerPoNumber" value="${transaction.customerPoNumber }" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].disposalVolume" size=6 data-varname="disposalVolume" value="${transaction.disposalVolume }"></td>
          <td>
            <select data-varname="disposalUom" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].disposalUom">
              <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
              <option ${transaction.disposalUom eq 'CA' ? 'selected' : '' } value="CA">CARTS</option>
              <option ${transaction.disposalUom eq 'EA' ? 'selected' : '' } value="EA">EACH</option>
              <option ${transaction.disposalUom eq 'GL' ? 'selected' : '' } value="GL">GALLONS</option>
              <option ${transaction.disposalUom eq 'LD' ? 'selected' : '' } value="LD">LOAD</option>
              <option ${transaction.disposalUom eq 'TN' ? 'selected' : '' } value="TN">TONS</option>
              <option ${transaction.disposalUom eq 'YD' ? 'selected' : '' } value="YD">YARDS</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="enterSubmittable" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].amtInvoicedFromHauler" size=12 data-varname="amtInvoicedFromHauler" value="${transaction.amountInvoicedFromHauler }" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="enterSubmittable" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].amtToBePaidToHauler" size=12 data-varname="amtToBePaidToHauler" value="${transaction.amountToBePaidToHauler }" /></td>
          <c:set value="${amountInvoicedFromHauler +  transaction.amountInvoicedFromHauler }" var="amountInvoicedFromHauler" scope="request" />
          <c:set value="${amountToBePaidToHauler +  transaction.amountToBePaidToHauler}" var="amountToBePaidToHauler" scope="request" />
          <c:if test="${multipleAccounts }">
            <td>
              <select data-varname="bulkMode" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].bulkMode">
                <option ${transaction.bulkMode eq ' ' ? 'selected' : '' } value=" ">ADD</option>
                <option ${transaction.bulkMode eq 'UPDATE' ? 'selected' : '' } value="UPDATE">UPDATE</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="enterSubmittable" name="invoiceEntry[${iterStatus.count -1 }].rowIdentifier" size=12 data-varname="rowIdentifier" value="${transaction.rowIdentifier }" readonly/></td>
          </c:if>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>


method for adding the record
var doSubmit = false;

function doUpdate() {
  if (doSubmit) {
    return true;
  }
  
  $('#writeTable tr').removeClass("table-danger");
  
  //reset table errors
  $('.detailInputTable tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("table-danger");
    $(this).find('td:last').html("&nbsp;");
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '${requestScope['
    javax.servlet.forward.request_uri ']}/validate',
    data: $('#detailForm').serialize(),
    async: false,
    statusCode: {
      200: function(response) {
        doSubmit = true;
        postHeader();
        $('#detailForm').submit();

      },
      412: function(xhr) {
        doSubmit = false;
        var data = xhr.responseJSON;
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
          var rowId = item.uiRowNumber;
          var errList = "<ul>";
          $.each(item.errors, function(index2, error) {
            errList += "<li>" + error.errorMessage + "</li>";
          });
          errList += "</ul>";
          var row = $('#row' + rowId);
          row.addClass('table-danger');
          var lasttd = row.find('td:last');
          lasttd.html('<em class="fa fa-exclamation-circle detailError" data-msg="' + errList + '" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px"></em>');
        });
        initDetailErrors();
      }
    }
  });

  return doSubmit;
}


chaining logic
function initChainedSelect(rowNumber) {
  $("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "bulkKey\\.site").chained("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "bulkKey\\.account");
  $("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "container").chained("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "bulkKey\\.account");
  $("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "chargeType").chained("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "container");
  $("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "chargeCode").chained("#invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "container, #invoiceEntry" + rowNumber + "chargeType");
}

whenever two different accounts are used to add I want only two to be added no duplicated records should obtain

I guess that your form is submitting when you click the button (maybe you need to use preventDefault), and then submitting again when you call $('#detailForm').submit(); in the success function, so you get 2 submits and 2 (or 4) records.

may I add preventDefault after $('#detailForm').submit(); ?

I would try to put preventDefault at the top of doUpdate

Don't use onsubmit event for submitting your data, because it will fire twice to the backend.

@RomanC what could be the alternative for form submission ?

@James adding preventDefault did not worked as expected.
